# How do I properly serialize a JSON file that contains an array of strings

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

I have this array of strings:
`["https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/3f47b1c848763f156778015a20da91b5f365ea93.jpg","https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/22ee83228be55bce16bc8c6e91790700229892b9.jpg"]`

I'm trying to do this, but it's not working.

```
@Serializable
data class ShibePhoto(

    @SerialName("photos")
    val photos: List<String>
)
```

I'm getting this error

`kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 0: Expected start of the object '{', but had '[' instead at path: $[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically saying that the response is of the form

`{"photos":[...]}`

Instead of just

`[...]`

What you need to do is not even have the class `ShibePhoto` and use `List<String>` directly wherever you had `ShibePhoto` in your code